# Flutter- Reduce padding between hintText and suffixIcon for TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a TextFormField with hintText and suffixIcon. Currently the hint text is overflowing with ellipsis indication. There is a lot of space between hint text and the suffix icon which I want to reduce or at least remove the overflow and show the text completely.

I tried to achieve this with setting the hintStyle property by making the overflow visible, but still the ellipsis is appearing. How can we resolve this?

[image]

```
TextFormField(
        initialValue:'Value',
        onTap:() {},
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText:'Select Date',
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.visible),
          isDense: true,
          suffixIcon: suffixIcon,
          suffixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(
            minWidth: 25,
            minHeight: 25,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: when I run your code the text field UI is mismatched with the text field you have added in the question?

Comment: @nagendranag I have just updated the question with correct text

Comment: Are you from PayPal by any chance ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d, No I'm not. :)

Comment: Ah never mind I know one by same name and your DP did not help either :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isDense: true`

*his will remove the default content padding
now you can customize it here or add padding widget*

Then, You can use **Content padding** to give padding to the widgets inside.

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. Try to add **[hintMaxLines](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/hintMaxLines.html)**,

```
TextFormField(
   // initialValue:'Value',
    onTap:() {},
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText:'Some Text',
      hintMaxLines: 2,
      hintStyle: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.visible),
      isDense: true,
      suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.date_range),
      suffixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(
        minWidth: 25,
        minHeight: 25,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Your Result-> [image]

Comment: hintMaxLines would help, but that also changes the textField height dynamically based on the length of text which I don't want to

Comment: but main thing there is no space in your design  code I have taste it on my device